# How to remove SnoreToast in node-notifier in Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js

node-notifier displays **SnoreToast** at windows 10 notification.

How can I remove SnoreToast at both and SnoreToast's icon too?

[image]

[image]

**js**

```
function noti_click() {
        const notifier = require('node-notifier');
        // Object
        notifier.notify({
            title  : 'Admin panel',
            message: 'Server is provisioned',
            icon   : './facebook.png',
            appId  : 'cyber'
        }),
            function (error, response, metadata) {
                console.log(response, metadata);
            }
    }
```

**html**

```
<button onclick="noti_click()">Noti</button>
```

Comment: It may help you. https://github.com/mikaelbr/node-notifier/issues/154

Comment: Use zero-width space: `appID: "\u{200B}"`

Answer (score 3):

You can add appID: 'Your application ID' in the notify method. This will resolve your issue in the production environment

Answer (score 0):

You have used the wrong parameter. You have to use `appID` instead of `appId`. Note the capitalization.

Additionally, the value can't be empty. A string containing a space (`" "`) should work.